# Mysql function return system result

Tags: mysql, bash, function

In mysql, I'm trying to create a function that will return the result of a bash command. I've created a simplified version of what I'm trying to do to make it easier to understand.

I have a file called mycmd.sh, and inside it, I have this line:

```
echo $1 'test'
```

When in mysql, I execute the sh file it is working fine

```
system ~/mycmd.sh 'test'
```

But I would like to be able to call it while doing a select in mysql, something like this

```
select myFunc(username) from user;
```

The result will be that, every username will have a "test" after it.

The problem is when I try to create the mysql function

```
CREATE FUNCTION myFunc(s VARCHAR(500)) RETURNS VARCHAR(505)
RETURN SYSTEM ~/mycmd.sh s;
```

I always get the error: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '~/mycmd.sh s' at line 2

I tried putting it in quote, or in a variable, or in a prepared statement, but nothing seem to work...

Anyone have an idea how to do so?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately what you are trying to do isn't possible without using a UDF (User Defined Plugin). The `system` command you're using is part of the MySQL shell, not an actual MySQL function, which is why it doesn't work in the function you're trying to define.

The only other option I can think of is to write a procedure that imitated whatever your external command was going to do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, meanwhile I did use a udf to solve my problem